# Gridworld Case Study (java) : Mac Errors

Tags: java, macos, gridworld

I am having an issue when running gridworld.
The GUI runs correctly but there are these annoying errors:

```
Dec  3 19:44:01 MyName-MacBook-Pro.local java[4085] <Error>: CGContextGetCTM: invalid context 0x0
Dec  3 19:44:01 MyName-MacBook-Pro.local java[4085] <Error>: CGContextSetBaseCTM: invalid context 0x0
Dec  3 19:44:01 MyName-MacBook-Pro.local java[4085] <Error>: CGContextGetCTM: invalid context 0x0
Dec  3 19:44:01 MyName-MacBook-Pro.local java[4085] <Error>: CGContextSetBaseCTM: invalid context 0x0
```

Any ideas?

According to javatester.org, I am running "Java Version : 1.7.0_09 from Oracle Corporation."

I am running mac os x 10.7.5.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Harmless.  These starting appearing one day for me too whenever I opened a Java GUI, but they never manifested into any noticeable issue.

Then one day, as mysteriously as they appeared, they went away.  I'm running 10.8.  Some recent system or Java update took care of them.